# Problem Inserting Multiple Arrays into Database

Tags: php, mysql

I was inserting multiple arrays into my database using this code:

```
$queries_cols = array(); 

for($i=0; $i<count($cols); $i++) 
{ 
    $queries_cols [] = "('".$cols[$i]."','".$int_manha1_1[$i]."','".$int_manha1_2[$i]."','" .$int_tarde2_1[$i]."','".$int_tarde2_2[$i]."','".$h1_1[$i].$h1_2[$i]."','".$h2_1[$i].$h2_2[$i]."')" ; 
}

$query_col = "INSERT into cols_ponto_diaria values '".implode(",", $queries_cols)."'";

$result = mysql_query($query_col) or die("Erro: ".mysql_error());
```

And when I submit the form it output an error:

`Erro: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''('Ricardo','08:30:00','12:15:00','14:45:00','18:00:00','0115','1215')'' at line 1`

Can anyone find where is the error? I've tried a few solutions but without any success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First port of call: Output the actual query that gets generated using `echo $query_col;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily find it by printing $query_col as soon as you have it ready.

Anyway, the error I believe is in the implode() call. You don't need the extra quotes.

So instead of

```
$query_col = "INSERT into cols_ponto_diaria values '".implode(",", $queries_cols)."'";
```

try

```
$query_col = "INSERT into cols_ponto_diaria values ".implode(",", $queries_cols);
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it. :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quote at the end of  this expression,

```
INSERT into cols_ponto_diaria values
```

Don't append the single quote at the end of the expression.

```
."'"
```

Comment: I saw your reply after I found the solution.

Thank you Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. I tried several things and I forgot to try this approach. :(

Sorry for disturbing.

Here's the correct syntax:

```
$query_col = "INSERT into cols_ponto_diaria values ".implode(",", $queries_cols);
```

regards